# How should I analysis the time complexity analysis of the two different codes?

Tags: loops, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

How should I analysis the time complexity analysis of the two different codes?

```
sum=0;
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    for(j=1; j<=n; j*=2)
          sum++;
```

If I change the outer loop to inner loop will it make a difference?

```
sum=0;
for(j=1; j<=n; j*=2)
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
          sum++;
```

Are they both O(nlogn)?

Edit : Will the second code lead to a geometric series as the number of loops internally seems to be affected by the outer loop? If it does,  will it not be O(nlogn)?

Answer (score 0):

They both have complexity equal to O(n log n).

Note that sum++ is O(1) operation.

This is so because the one which doubles every iteration (j in first code and i in second code) would iterate for only log n times.

Here, as the looping variables aren't dependent on each other, and only depends on n, so changing the outer loop to inner loop won't make any difference.

Edit(based on OP's edit) :

I didn't get what you mean by geometric series. But, if you're talking about the mathematical behavior of the code, I must add that it is not a geometric series as for every iteration of outer loop , the inner loop iterates for constant n times.

So, for log n outer loop iterations, the complexity of code = O(log n * n *1) = O(n log n).

Also, inner loop doesn't get affected by outer loop as it is solely dependent on n.

Comment: I edited my original post. I would like to know, will the second code lead to a geometric series as the number of loops internally seems to be affected by the outer loop?

Comment: @user292965 - I've made an edit based on your edit to the question. Check if it is clear to you.

Comment: @user292965 - If the answer helped, please mark the answer as accepted. Also upvote the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

### First fragment:

[image]

### Second fragment:

[image]

How I came up with the logarithm:

[image]

Source: http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt, slide 12.